# want to make some views invisible during runtime in android application

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my main .xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip"
    >

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textColor="@color/mbackground1"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="@string/decode_label"
android:padding="5dip" 
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/mytext"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@color/mbackground2" 
android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor" 
android:padding="5dip"
/>


 <TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/continue_label"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor"
android:padding="5dip"
/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/webbutton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/web_button"
android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor"
/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/continue_label1"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor"
android:padding="5dip"
/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/callbutton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/call_button"
android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor"
/>
<TextView

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/continue_label2"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor"
android:padding="5dip"
/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/emailbutton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/sendemail_button"
android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

i want that based on output at runtime it should show only one textview and button corresponding to that output. im defining layout in main.xml file and also i am ew in this field.

does any one have any idea.
thanks in advance

Comment: use setVisibility method. for hiding button  you can use button.setVisibility(View.GONE);.. you can use View.Visible for turning visibility ON.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you know how to get a reference to the views you defined, for example:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.emailbutton)
```

You will need to define an id to each and every view you want to use in the code, just like you did to the emailbutton:

```
android:id="@+id/emailbutton"
```

In order to set the visibility of a view you call:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

you have the option to set the visibility to `INVISIBLE` and `VISIBLE`.
Then you can play with the visibility as you like.
The differnece between `INVISIBLE` and `GONE` is that `GONE` removes the view completely from the layout while `INVISIBLE` "saves" the space this view takes.

You can see that in the API examples.

Answer (score 9):

To remove yourview in java code:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

To transparent yourview in java code:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

To remove yourview in Xml file:

```
<yourView
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

To transparent button in Xml file:

```
<yourView
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

to make a view visible or invisible try this:

```
yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use textView.setVisibility(View.GONE); - to make View Gone and textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); - to make view INVISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

The view's visibility can be changed using the `View.setVisibility()` method, check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) for more info. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Get the View by ID and make it invisible. For your "mytext" TextView for example:

```
TextView my = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext); // Get the view you want to manipulate
my.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                   // Make it invisible
my.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                     // Make it visible again
```

[Always check the documentation first!](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)